# connect to a kafka container from localhost

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I'm new to dockers.

I have to create a kafka container 
which will have a consumer container whose job is to consume and save to mongodb.

my docker-compose looks like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  consumer:
    image: springio/kafka-consumer
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - mongodb
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test:1:1"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: "mongodb"
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
      - MONGO_LOG_DIR=/dev/null
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
    ports:
        - 27017:27017
```

As far as I understand I couldn't use KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME as 'localhost' because then the consumer container would not be able to reach it (since it would try to connect to its own container localhost).
Therefore I name it 'kafka'.

Now, I want to run a producer (not a container) on my host machine (same machine the containers run).

The problem is, the minute I changed the KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME to be different than localhost, I cannot produce to kafka from the host machine producer.

1. Why can't I produce to  kafka? I thought when I stated ports: 9092:9092, I actually exported that port to the host machine, am I wrong?
2. What is the best way/s to reach the kafka from the host machine without using an additional container for the producer?

Any help would be appreciated!!

**EDIT:**

When I try to produce a message using kafka-console-producer, only when the KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME is not 'localhost', I get the following message:

> ERROR Error when sending message to topic test with key: null, value:
>   3 bytes with error:
>   (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s)
>   for test-0: 1503 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time

Comment: `9092:9092` mapping will allow you to reach that container using 'localhost` from outside of the container. Regardless of advertised listeners property, I believe

Comment: @cricket_007, when I KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME is localhost, the host java service can connect to kafka. The minute I change it to 'kafka', the java service cannot connect anymore... maybe I should do something else?

Comment: @cricket_007, can I somehow debug it to know what went wrong with it not connecting to kafka? thank you!

Comment: `kafka:9092` external to the container or its network will never work. You need to port map, as you have, then use localhost:9092... The same goes for Mongo

Answer (score 3):

It might not answer directly to your question, but this is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    hostname: kafka
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
      - "9092:9092"
    links: 
     - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://0.0.0.0:29092,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:29092,OUTSIDE://192.168.x.x:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  apollo:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyAppServer/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    volumes:
      - "./:/var/www"
```

And this is how I consume it, from outside the container (also out side VM in my case)

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server PLAINTEXT://192.168.x.x:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, kafka is not aware of the hostname `kafka` if you do not specify it and hence you are forced to use localhost or the ip from the docker engine.

You can solve this issue by adding the `hostname: kafka` entry in your `docker-compose.yml`, ie:

```
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    hostname: kafka
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test:1:1"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

[Here](https://github.com/Paizo/iotStreams) there is a sample project configured this way. Then if you want, you can add the same name in your machine host file as well and map it to your docker machine ip (windows default `10.0.75.1`). However this extra step is not needed for the services in your docker-compose to find kafka correctly.