# how to docker-compose spring-boot with kafka?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

Execution is working fine but I think I am missing something, because when I use the REST API it will show:

> (/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available

You may see this below. By the way I am new to Docker and Kafka.

I can't sent or get data to /GET/POST/PUT/DELETE since I use Docker.

My reference when i created this setup: https://github.com/codegard/kafka-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

```
//docker-compose.yaml

version: '3'

      
services: 
#----------------------------------------------------------------  
  productmicroservice:
    image: productmicroservice:latest
    container_name: productmicroservice
    depends_on:
      - product-mysqldb
      - kafka
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9001:8091"
    
    environment:
    
      - MYSQL_HOST=product-mysqldb
      - MYSQL_USER=oot
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_PORT=3306
      
      - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=${ACTIVE_PROFILE}"
      
    
#----------------------------------------------------------------      

  product-mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.0.28
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: product-mysqldb
    ports: 
      - "3307:3306"
    
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbpoc
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      
#----------------------------------------------------------------   

        
  zookeeper:
    image: elevy/zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
   
     
    
      
      
#----------------------------------------------------------------
 
    
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.11-2.0.0
    container_name: kafka
    
    restart: on-failure

    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 127.0.0.1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

```
//appication.yaml

spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=127.0.0.1:9092
product.kafkaServer= ${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}

spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=PLAINTEXT
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer

topic.name=producttopic
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.check_nullability=true



spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:${MYSQL_PORT:3306}/dbpoc
    username: root
    password: root
  
  
   
    
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
        physical-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
    hibernate.ddl-auto: update
    generate-ddl: false
    show-sql: false
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

  mvc:
   throw-exception-if-no-handler-found: true
  web:
    resources:
      add-mappings: false
        
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always
      continue-on-error: true

    
server:
  port: 8091
```

```
// .env

ACTIVE_PROFILE=dev
```

```
//Dockerfile

FROM openjdk:8-alpine
ADD target/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

```
//topic that i created

./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic producttopic
```

```
//trying to send data manualy in kafka
//working


//producer

bash-4.4# ./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 127.0.0.1:9092 --topic producttopic
>hellow
>

//comsumer

bash-4.4# ./kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic producttopic --from-beginning --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092
hellow
```

```
//sending data to from my rest api
//this is wrong but i dont know what is the reason

productmicroservice  | 2022-05-04 13:08:28.283  WARN 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
productmicroservice  | 2022-05-04 13:08:28.283  WARN 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
productmicroservice  | 2022-05-04 13:08:29.343  WARN 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

```
//fix reference below comment
//change made

//application.yaml

spring.kafka.topic.name=producttopic
topic.name=${spring.kafka.topic.name}

spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=kafka:9092
product.kafkaServer= ${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}


//docker-compose.yaml
//added to kafka environment

KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "producttopic:1:1"
KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9092,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9093

//manual get data in topic by consumer

./kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic producttopic --from-beginning --bootstrap-server localhost:9093

//code changes in spring

//for topic
@Value("${topic.name}")

//for bootstrapserver
@Value("${product.kafkaServer}")

//must note

wurstmeister/kafka:2.11-2.0.0

I use "2.11-2.0.0" since its compatible with jdk 8 where latest give me error and my project required jdk 8
```

Comment: i answered a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50219147/3224238

Comment: Did you not read the duplicate post I marked on your previous question and the section between two containers on the same host? What could be changed about the description if it is unclear?

Comment: I edited my post question and added the fix code/changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `127.0.0.1:9092` as the Kafka container endpoint from the Java container. From a container, `localhost` targets the container itself, this won't work.

Docker Compose will set a default [network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in which your services are reachable by their name.
Therefore I think you should change your **application.yaml** to:

```yaml
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=kafka:9092
# ...
```